# What is Laurie Paul really trying to argue at the core of decision making before transformative experience?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I've been reading Laurie Paul's Transformative Experience, and understand how we are not able to make "rational" decisions whatsoever because we are not capable of knowing the actual experience before making the decision. 
She also suggests making an authentic decision (since rational decision is not possible), but I really don't get the conclusion of her argument? Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.